# Given a local martingale $M$ the running supremum $N_t=\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|M_s|$ is locally integrable

Tags: martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

I am trying to understand a detail of the proof of Theorem VI.82 of the book by Dellacherie and Meyer.

**Theorem** Let $M$ be a local martingale and let $N_t=\sup_{s\leq t}\left|M_s\right|$. Then $N$ is locally integrable.

The proof is elegant and (looks) simple. The authors consider the localizing sequence $R_n$ that makes the stopped process $M^{(R_n)}$ an integrable martingale and the sequence $P_n$ given by $P_n=\inf\{t\geq0\mid \left|M_t\right|\geq n\}$. Then they define
$$
S_n = R_n\wedge P_n
$$
We clearly have that $|M|<n$ on the stochastic interval $[0,S_n[$. This should imply that
$$
N_{S_n}\leq n
$$
and, for me, it would be enough to conclude that $N$ is locally integrable (because it is also increasing, so once stopped at $S_n$ it is bounded).
Nevertheless, they say that
$$
N_{S_n}\leq n \vee |M_{S_n}|\quad (1)
$$
having proved before (it is not difficult) that $|M_{S_n}|$ is integrable. Any idea of how to obtain the $(1)$ and why we really need it?

ps = it looks like we do not really need the property of being a martingale for the stopped process, but just integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $M$ may (and often will) have a jump at $S_n$, so it is quite possible that $|M_{S_n}|>n$. So actually
$$
N_{S_n} \le |M_{S_n}| \vee \sup_{s<S_n} |M_s| \le |M_{S_n}| \vee n.
$$

Comment: You are right, and now I am realizing that it is $N_{S_n}\leq \max(|M_{S_n}|,n)$ not the minimum, sorry.  Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @AlmostSureUser, sure, thanks.